# Color row based on cell value

Tags: javascript

I have a table with a particular column, where the cells only contain either "R" , "N" or "Y". I want to color the row based on either of those values mentioned. Any advice would be helpful

Here is what I have but its not changing the row color

```
  var rows = document.getElementById("trans_separate").getElementsByTagName("tbody")
  [0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // loops through each row
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

            if (cells[14].innerText == R)
                rows[i].className = "red";

            else if (cells[14].innerText == Y)
                rows[i].className = "Yellow";

            else if (cells[1].innerText == N)
                null

 }
```

Comment: `if (cells[14].innerText == 'R') ... `

Comment: Console should have directed you straight to the answer. If you plan on working with Javascript, learning how to use the console and either Chrome Debugger or FireBug is essential.

Comment: Do you really need to fetch tbody then tr and then cells? I suppose `document.getElementById("trans_separate").getElementsByTagName('td')` would be enough to get all cells you need.

Comment: Yea I could have done that. Thanks

Comment: What if the `thead` has `td`s instead of `th`s? There could be an issue. Coding ambiguously will hurt you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("trans_separate").getElementsByTagName("tbody")
  [0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // loops through each row
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

            if (cells[0].innerHTML == 'R')
                rows[i].className = "red";

            if (cells[0].innerHTML == 'Y')
                rows[i].className = "yellow";           
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mMFwQ/4/

Comment: `if (cells[0].textContent === 'R') rows[i].className = "red";`

Comment: I would check to see if `cells[0].innerText` is undefined, if so: get `cells[0].textContent`

Comment: textContent does not work in old IE browsers.
May be
`if ((cells[0].textContent || cells[0].innerText) == 'R') rows[i].className = "red";`
can help situation?

Comment: When I apply an "alert(cells[14].innerText); "I get the return value in the cell but when I try to apply the className to style the row nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Firefox on Ubuntu: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TKWB5/1)

p.s. Should be an `else-if`. If the text inside is `'R'`, then you should not evaluate for `'Y'`.

```
var rows = document.getElementById("trans_separate").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    row = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    var cell = getText(row[0]);
    if (cell === 'R') rows[i].className = "red";
    else if (cell === 'Y') rows[i].className = "yellow";
}

function getText(cell) {
    return (cell.innerText == undefined) ? cell.textContent : cell.innerText;
}
```