# Change row color of a cell in a table using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change my row colour according to my  tag using pure HTML CSS or JS and not with any external src since it is not supported in the application I am using where I want to do this.

Below is my code:

```css
table { 
  width: 750px; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  margin:20px auto;
}
tr:nth-of-type(even) { 
  background: #eee;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
th { 
  background: #1489b8; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: default; 
}

td, th { 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 3px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 15px;
}
h3, p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <h3>Hi User,</h3>
  <p>An alert is created. Following are the details.</p>
</head>
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Description</th>
      <td>working</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <td>Shutdown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Machine </th>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Type</th>
      <td>Sensor Machine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Severity</th>
      <td>Low</td>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The last  tag reads "Low" in this example, I want the row colour to change to green. If it reads medium it should change to "yellow".
Any way this could happen?

Comment: the only way this can happen is via Javascript. Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: If you slightly change your table to something having 'low' or 'medium' or whatever inside the HTML tag, then it will be easily possible via CSS. For example: `<tr data-severity="low">...`

Comment: @cloned , i tried alternating row colors. Really new to JS. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Or for example using classes: `<tr class="severity-low">...`. But if you can't change the table, then you have to use JavsScript. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content

Comment: For alternating rows I would use css `tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}` and `tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}`. To set a color based on content @Anton is right. In this case I would also set a class using js. `var element = document.getElement....; element.classList.add("mystyle");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color row based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510708/color-row-based-on-cell-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply and the **easiest** way is to use **Javascript** [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to get all the `td's` in your table and check their [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and apply the color using `if` condition

If the condition `matches` with the `severity` levels then you can `style` the `background` whatever you prefer to use.

**Live Working Example:**

```js
let getTds = document.querySelectorAll('table td')

getTds.forEach(function(row) {
  //Low
  if (row.textContent == 'Low') {
    row.style.background = 'green'
  }
  //Medium
  if (row.textContent == 'Medium') {
    row.style.background = 'yellow'
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 750px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #eee;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background: #1489b8;
  color: white;
  font-weight: default;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

h3,
p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <h3>Hi User,</h3>
  <p>An alert is created. Following are the details.</p>
</head>
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Description</th>
      <td>working</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <td>Shutdown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Machine </th>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Type</th>
      <td>Sensor Machine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Severity</th>
      <td>Low</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Description</th>
      <td>working</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Parameter</th>
      <td>Shutdown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Machine </th>
      <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Type</th>
      <td>Sensor Machine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> Severity</th>
      <td>Medium</td>
    </tr>

  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! this worked. I have upvoted and ticked your answer! Thank you so much!!! @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Sca but this solution is only for table cells, not for rows... I hope you will adjust it by yourself.

Comment: @Anton thats not a big deal at all. We just need to check the `textContent` and apply color to that row as well :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I am sure you can do this, but curious if Sca can do this as well :)

Comment: @Sca Please let me know if you need any other help with i am happy to help further :)